# Issues with migrating database phpmyadmin

Tags: sql, database, wordpress, phpmyadmin

So, I'm trying to update a WordPress staging site. I've exported the db and imported it in the same phpmyadmin on the same server, but after importing I get the following error when trying to update tables.

> Current selection does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete > features are not available.

I did find a solution that involved editing a column to make it primary key option, and that worked for the wp_options table and I was able to update the site url and home url, but I'm now getting fatal errors on the site and I'm still unable to edit other tables of course.

> Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: Error saving action: Database error. in >/home/domain/staging.domain.com/wp->content/plugins/woocommerce/packages/action->scheduler/classes/data-?>stores/ActionScheduler_DBStore.php:75

This is just one of many fatal errors.

Does anyone know why this happens and how I can prevent it, rather than editing tables, how can I make sure the import of the db 'clean' with no issues?

Answer (score 0):

You can try exporting your database with bellow option
"Database system or older MySQL server to maximize output compatibility with: mysql 40"

and re importing it.